# Is it possible to make clickable links using Logger.log?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to make clickable links using Logger.log?

I have this code that log url `Logger.log(url);` that logs text in console.

[image]

I wonder if this is possible to make that url clickable by using `Logger.log`, `console.log` or any other approach?

Comment: It's not a built-in function. Once said that, please search this site and https://developers.google.com/apps-script thoroughly, share what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. Also show what you have tried.

Comment: @Rubén I haven't found anything like that here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging

Comment: Thanks for  your reply. As mentioned in my previous comment, it's not a built-in function (Logger.log, console.log can't create clickable URL in the Google Apps Script execution logs), regarding "any other aproach" that is way too broad... you might use an userscript / userstyle, a browswer extension, instead of logging to the execution log you might do it to a Google spreadsheet, document, etc. create a custom dialog, a web application using Apps Script among other possible others approaches. Keep searching, choose one approach, show what you tried. (you could make multiple questions )

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Comment: @Michael Comments are not intended to be used for extended discussions. Please remember we have [meta] and [chat]. The first is to discuss the workings of this community, the second might be used to chat about almost everything, while it's related to the site scope and be of interest of this community.